# uploading files start from beginning when app killed in flutter or disconnect from internet and reconnect again

Tags: flutter, dart

i am uploading files to firebase cloud storage in background with [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) in flutter, it works good when the app is in background but when the app killed by user the uploading process starts from beginning and also when the user disconnect internet and reconnect it starts uploading process from beginning.

Here is my upload function

```
  Future<void> uploadVideo() async {
    List<String> filesPath = [];

    await Future.forEach(imgSource, (AssetEntity element) async {
      File file = await element.file;
      filesPath.add(file.path);
    });

    await Workmanager().registerOneOffTask(
      "1",
      uploadFileTask,
      inputData: <String, dynamic>{
        'filesPath': filesPath,
      },
      constraints: Constraints(
        networkType: NetworkType.connected,
        requiresBatteryNotLow: true,
      ),
      backoffPolicy: BackoffPolicy.exponential,
      existingWorkPolicy: ExistingWorkPolicy.keep,

    );

  }


// Here is callbackDispatcher function


void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    switch (task) {
      case uploadFileTask:
        try {
          List<dynamic> dynamicType = inputData["filesPath"];
          List<String> filesPath =
              dynamicType.map((e) => e.toString()).toList();

          await Firebase.initializeApp();
          int counter = 1;

          List<String> downloadUrlLinks = [];


          await Future.forEach(filesPath, (String filePath) async {
            File file = File(filePath);
            String fullPath = getRandomName(file.path);
            String storagePath = "test/$fullPath";

            print("Full path HM" + fullPath);

            String downloadUrl = await CloudService.uploadFileWithProgressBar(
              file: file,
              filePath: storagePath,
              maxLength: filesPath.length,
              uploadedLength: counter,
            );

            downloadUrlLinks.add(downloadUrl);

            counter++;
          });
          await NotificationService.finishedNotification(
              title: 'Uploading files finished');

          print("download link:     " + downloadUrlLinks.toString());

          downloadUrlLinks = [];

        } catch (e) {
          print("uploading error" + e.toString());
        }

        break;
    }

    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```

Comment: Please put the code as text, not as an image.

Comment: i edited it please check it again